# Сделать кодировку единую UTF-8 в Mysqli

Tags: mysqli, php, кодировка

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в базу данных делаю запрос на добавление записи

```
 $new_user = "INSERT INTO `users` (`login`,`mail`,`password`,`reg_about`,`reg_like_game`,`reg_date`,`reg_ip`) VALUES ('$login','$mail','$password','$about','$like_game','$reg_date','$reg_ip')";                 
                  $register_user = mysqli_query ($link,$new_user); 
                  if($register_user) {echo "<br />Регистрация прошла успешна";
```

в базу данных добавляется следующее РћС‚ Р·РЅР°РєРѕРјС‹С… (а именно в поле где русские буквы) как сделать кодировку единую UTF-8... Подскажите пожалуйста)

Comment: google в помощь [ВОТ][1]


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/37043/php-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-utf-8-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81-mysql

Comment: @Дмитрий Астафьев, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: @Дмитрий Астафьев, оба расширения работают с одним и тем же сервером mysql и посылаемые команды (не функции, а именно команды) будут идентичны.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вероятно, что сами таблицы должны иметь кодировку

> utf8_general_ci

Comment: так и есть :)

Answer (score 0):

mysqli_set_charset ($c, "utf8");